# How to implement sections in table view containing SQLite3 database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, sqlite

I have an application which display large amount of values using UITableView and imported sqlite3 database. Now i face problem that i need to make sections for elements. It must be similar for default application "contacts" in iPhone, but i don't want for that section to sort elements only for first letter. Database contains data about food, so sections should be like "Bread", "Meat", "Fish", etc.

Please help, any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make a NSDictionary whose key is title to be displayed and value is NSArray which consist of all the objects that contain. Now do the following :

> ```
> - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
>   return [[dict allkeys]count];
>    }
> ```

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection(NSInteger)section           
{

     //Number of rows it should expect should be based on the section
     NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:[[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:section]];
     return [array count];
}



  - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];

  }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  // Set up the cell...

  cell.text = [[dict objectForkey:[[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexpath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell;
 }
```

Comment: dict ia a NSDictionary whose key is title to be displayed and object is NSArray which consist of all the objects that contain

Comment: Please tell me where to declare NSDictionary

Comment: declare in viewWillLoad functions if the data is not changeable otherwise in viewWillAppear

Comment: i tried NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:food, @"food", nil]; but Xcode burst with error - undeclared identifier dict, when i tried to  writhereturn [[dict allkeys]count];

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862872/how-to-implement-sections-in-table-view-containing-sqlite-database please visit the link