# How to implement sections in table view containing SQLite database?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

So, i have UITableView, large amount of data which is displayed with a many rows, and i want to make sections (like default contacts application and its sections). So there is my code (listViewController.m file):

```
#import "FailedBanksListViewController.h"
#import "FailedBankDatabase.h"
#import "FailedBankInfo.h"
#import "FailedBanksDetailViewController.h"
#import "BIDAppDelegate.h"

@implementation FailedBanksListViewController
@synthesize failedBankInfos = _failedBankInfos;
@synthesize details = _details;


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]];;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.failedBankInfos = [FailedBankDatabase database].failedBankInfos;
    self.title = @"Продукты";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    self.failedBankInfos = nil;
    self.details = nil;

}
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


}

#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [_failedBankInfos count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_failedBankInfos count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    // Set up the cell...
    FailedBankInfo *info = [_failedBankInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = info.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", info.city, info.state];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.details == nil) {
        self.details = [[FailedBanksDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FailedBanksDetailViewController" bundle:nil];        
    }
    FailedBankInfo *info = [_failedBankInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _details.uniqueId = info.uniqueId;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_details animated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.failedBankInfos = nil;
}


@end
```

Comment: Okay, that is your code. What is your issue?

Comment: I want to make sections in TableView, all of examples i have seen not working with SQlite, just simple NSarrays. I want sections like - "Food", "Meat", "Fish", etc., not just first letters..

Comment: What did you try? Where was a problem? Simple saying "give me your code" does not work at SO.

Comment: Sorry for being stupid, but i came here because i didn't find anything that could help , any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

With your code you should have multiple sections (each one exactly equal than the others).
The idea for a multiple section table view is (normally) to have a 2 dimensional array (not 1 dimensional as is your case). Then each row would represent a section for your table view.

For example, if you have an array structured this way (and I know you can't initialize it this way):

```
arr = {
  {'apple','orange','banana'},
  {'CD-Rom', 'DVD', 'BR-Disk'},
  {'AK-47', 'Rocket launcher', 'Water gun'}
}
```

your number of sections method may return `[arr count]` and the number of rows for section s may return `[[arr objectAtIndex:s] count]`. And remember that you can set the title for each section with the table view datasource method `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`.

If you want to load the info from a SQLite DB, nothing may change. It's exactly the same but you will have to keep of the way to get your data.

When you thing you understand all this stuff then checkout the [Core Data framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html).